# Preimage of a compact set

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, is the preimage $f^{-1}([0,1])$ also compact?

I'm trying to check the two conditions that it's closed and bounded. I know how to show it's closed, but I don't know how to show that it's bounded. Can I just say the domain is unbounded because it's $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: FYI: A continuous mapping $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces is called [proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) if $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for all compact set $K\subset Y$.

Comment: If $f$ is proper. Continuity is not necessary.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not generally. The pre-image is closed because $f$ is continuous. But it need not be bounded.  The simplest example is to let $f(x,y)=0$ for all $x, y.$ Then $\{0\}$ is compact and $f^{-1}\{0\}=\mathbb R^2.$

Answer (score 13):

It's not true. not even for $\mathbb R $ to $\mathbb R$. Consider $\sin(x)$

Answer (score 7):

$f(x_1, ... ,x_n) = \sin(5x_1)$ is an example of a continuous $f$ with  unbounded preimage of $f([0,1])$.

Comment: You repeat a notational impreciseness of the question. The preimage under $f$ of the subset $[0,1]$ (subset of the codomain) is what we talk about. This preimage could be written $f^{-1}([0,1])$, typically. But there is nothing called $f([0,1])$ in the present setup. (We do have the image $f([0,1]^n)$ of the $n$-cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I do not think that was what was meant.)

Answer (score 3):

When we say a function is bounded, it means *for every element in the domain of the function* its value always lies between two numbers, the bounds.
In case the domain is unbounded we get a function that maps an unbounded set to a bounded set.

Now reversing the viewpoint for this function we can say the pre-image of a bounded set  is an unbounded set.

That is what kotomord's answer above  achieves. Take a well-known bounded function such as the sine function and compose this with the function $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto x_1$.

Writing $v$ for an element in your domain we can also see that $v\mapsto \frac1{1+\|v\|}\|v\|$ is also one such function (here $\|v\|$ means length of the vector $v$).